# Automatic CSS height

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website footer. As supposed to be, it's rendered after the page's content, but when the page's content is less than the browser's height is annoying to see it on the middle of the page.

I'm correcting this behavior manually setting the footer to `position:absolute; bottom:0`, but doing so, breaks the footer when the content is greater than the browsers height. There is any way to automate this?

The content is just a div, with no aditional style and normally, the footer is `position:relative; bottom:0`. The website could be seen here: http://vestibulandos.oplex.com.br

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper {
margin: 0 auto -60px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
 }
 
/* FOOTER BOTTOM --------------------------------------------------------*/
 
.footer, .push {
    height: 60px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
 
#footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: But, what if the footer has dynamic height, because when logged in appear more links... But anyways, thanks.

Comment: It's really tricky to do a dynamic sticky footer without javascript. If you have some way of controling the markup based on whether or not the user is logged in, you could add a class to your markup and change things accordingly.